# Can't establish refresh time in Oracle materialized view on prebuilt table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, materialized-views

I'm trying to create a materialized view on prebuilt table with this syntax

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "STORE"  
ON PREBUILT TABLE
WITH REDUCED PRECISION  
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
START WITH SYSDATE+4/1440
NEXT SYSDATE + 1/24
USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS 
(
(SELECT
    t1.field1
    t1.field2
    t1.field3
    t3.LAT AS LAT,
    t3.LNG AS LNG,  
    t4.ID AS T4_ID
    FROM T1@STORE_DBLINK t1
    INNER JOIN T4 t4 ON t1.T4_ID = t4.ID
    LEFT JOIN T3@STORE_DBLINK t3 ON t3.STORE_NUMBER = t1.NUMBER
    WHERE ((t1.id = (
        SELECT MAX(t2.id)  
        FROM T2@STORE_DBLINK t2 
        WHERE t2.number=t1.number
        ))
))
UNION
  (SELECT te.field1,
    te.field2,
    te.field3,
    te.LAT  LAT,
    te.LNG  LNG,
    te.T4_ID
FROM STORE_TMP te
WHERE STORE_NUMBER not in (select DISTINCT NUMBER from T1S@STORE_DBLINK)));
```

This query creates the materialized view correctly. However, when I "Edit" the materialized view via SqlDeveloper the refresh period is disabled, and the rollback segment appears like "Unspecified".

Furthermore, if I try to change Refresh "On demand" to  a time period with next refresh, it nevers complete the change. The same thing happens if I execute:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW STORE
REFRESH FORCE
START WITH SYSDATE+4/1440
NEXT SYSDATE+1/24;
```

Maybe this is due to the fact that I'm using a complex materialized view? Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What statement do you use to "Edit" the materialized view? Does sqldeveloper let you see it?

Comment: When I said that I "Edit" the view what I was really trying to say was that I click "Edit" in the materialized view's contextual menu. I do this to see the properties or to verify that everything went ok during creation.

Comment: Maybe it's some kind of bug. Because I've found another way to see the next materialized view's refresh, and it appears to be correct. My sqldeveloper is in Spanish so I'm not sure about the exact translation of the menu option, but it could be DBMS Jobs. I've found under this directory all the materialized views that I have programmed with auto refresh.